# How to assign a function from content.js to a shortcut in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm stuck trying to run a function placed in `content.js` by a shortcut.

I tested a running of a simple function out of `background.js`, and it worked for me - I added to `manifest.json` these lines:

```
   "commands":{
  "run-script": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Alt+1",
      "windows": "Alt+1",
      "mac": "Command+E"
    },
    "description": "Run",
    "global": true
  }
}
```

and just "wore" my function with

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
//myFunc ...
});
```

But not in the `content.js` - I get just an error here.

This is my content script - the function I want to be run by shortcut is from the beginning to line 54.

**content.js**

```
//Listening for double click on the page
$(document).dblclick(function(e){
    chrome.storage.local.get(['enabled'], function(res){
        
        if(res.enabled)
        {
            if((e.pageX+400) < screen.availWidth)
            {
                innerDiv.css("left", e.pageX);
            }
            else
            {
                innerDiv.css("right", e.pageX);
            }
            if((e.pageY+300) < document.body.clientHeight)
            {
                innerDiv.css("top", e.pageY);
            }
            else
            {
                innerDiv.css("bottom", e.pageY);
            }

            innerDiv.css("left", e.pageX);
            innerDiv.css("top", e.pageY);
            //getting selected / highlighted word
            var word = window.getSelection().toString().trim();

            if(word.length==0)
                return;

            //Stating that extension is going to request definition from api
            innerDivBody.html("Fetching defenition...");
            //fading Up popup
            innerDiv.fadeIn();
            innerDivBody.empty();
            setupHeader(word);

            //Ajax request to get definition of selected word

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({word:word}, function(content){
                innerDivBody.append(content);
            });
        }
    });
});

//detecting click on outside popup to hide  popup
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.target.id != 'mzrdiv')
    {
        innerDiv.hide();
    }
});


//popup outer div which is appended to page
var outerDiv = $("<div></div>");
//setting id 
outerDiv.attr('id', 'mzrdiv');
//appending outer div
document.documentElement.appendChild(outerDiv[0]);
//Using dom shadow to avoid mixing up of page styles
var root = outerDiv[0].attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
//inner div of popup
var innerDiv = $("<div></div>");
innerDiv.css(inner_div_css);
var peak = $("<div></div>");
innerDiv.append(peak);
peak.css(peak_css);

var innerDivBody = $("<div></div>");
innerDivBody.css(inner_div_body_css)
innerDiv.append(innerDivBody);

//appending inner div to shadow dom
root.appendChild(innerDiv[0]);

function setupHeader(word)
{
    var innerDivHeader = $("<div></div>");
    innerDivHeader.css(inner_div_header_css);
    var wordSpan = $("<span></span>");
    wordSpan.css(word_span_css);
    wordSpan.html(word);
    innerDivHeader.append(wordSpan)
    var btn_close = $("<button></button>");
    btn_close.css(btn_close_css);
    btn_close.click(function(){
        innerDiv.hide();
    })
    innerDivHeader.append(btn_close);
    innerDivBody.append(innerDivHeader);
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    chrome.storage.local.get(['enabled'], function(res){
        if(res.enabled)
        {
            chrome.storage.local.set({enabled:false}, function(){
                chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                    path:'icon32gray.png'
                })
            });
        }
        else
        {
            chrome.storage.local.set({enabled:true}, function(){
                chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                    path:'icon32.png'
                })
            });   
        }
    });
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['enabled'], function(res){
    if(typeof(res.enabled) == "undefined")
    {
        chrome.storage.local.set({enabled:true}, function(){
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                path:'icon32.png'
            });
        });  
    }
    else if(res.enabled)
    {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path:'icon32.png'
        });
    }
    else
    {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path:'icon32gray.png'
        });
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    $.get('https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/'+request.word, function(res){
        var content = "Not Found";
        if($(res).find(".lemma__determiner").length>0)
        {
            content = $(res).find(".lemma__determiner")[0].outerHTML;
        }
        sendResponse(content);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr){
        //If request error show word is not found        
        var content = "Not Found";
        sendResponse(content);
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Use chrome.commands in the background script and [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) with the command id to your content script.

Comment: You could use chrome.contextMenu API to handle the user selection (both whole word or part of that). Double click event doesn't need anymore